# Using HashLocationStrategy with Adal causes infinite routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

In in my angular cli app I'm using adal-angular4 for login authentication. When deployed in Azure the app works fine when the routing starts from homepage with the login flow. But refreshing the page on any other route gives an 404 ERROR.

ERROR: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Found out that Hashlocationstrategy solves this issue so I added it to my AppModule

[image: My AppModule]

This puts my app in localhost to loop in login stage. The app never reaches the home page.[image: Initial load of localhost:4200][image: routing loop]

The app keeps looping these two routes. Is there anything to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a web.config file to my app and also including it in the dist build folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico|.eot|.woff2|.woff|.svg|.ttf)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```